# All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, yaml, google-compute-engine

I used Google compute engine to set up a cluster of three cassandra nodes.
After running the "nodetool status" I get:

```
antoniogallo88@cassandra-7m0w:~$ nodetool status
Datacenter: europe-west1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.240.41.185   56.28 KB   256     33.2%             edf4c2c8-f746-4c86-8b1e-4d4317788de9  b
UN  10.240.145.130  56.31 KB   256     30.6%             76025d1d-b5e4-4510-afd9-e0c52ae4aa2b  b
UN  10.240.194.231  60.94 KB   256     36.2%             1c5594d6-4a62-4cb7-bb4e-ab15545af6a0  b
```

So, all works fine.

Also the cqlsh command works well.

My problem is when I run the following:

```
package com.example.cassandra;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;

    public class SimpleClient {
       private Cluster cluster;

       public void connect(String node, int port) {
          cluster = Cluster.builder()
               // .addContactPoints("10.240.41.185", "10.240.145.130", "10.240.194.231").withPort(port).build();
                  .addContactPoints(node).withPort(port).build();

          Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
          System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", 
                metadata.getClusterName());
          for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) {
             System.out.printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",
                   host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());
          }
       }

       public void close() {
          cluster.close();;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SimpleClient client = new SimpleClient();
          client.connect("10.240.41.185", 9042);
          client.close();
       }
    }
```

I then get:

```
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.240.41.185:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/10.240.41.185:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:193)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1148)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:313)
    at com.example.cassandra.SimpleClient.connect(SimpleClient.java:15)
    at com.example.cassandra.SimpleClient.main(SimpleClient.java:30)
```

In cassandra.yaml:

```
    start_native_transport: true
    rpc_address = 0.0.0.0
    native_transport_port: 9042
listen_address: 10.240.145.130
```

If i have to edit cassandra.yaml file, how I could do this if I'm using google compute engine?

Thanks

Comment: In Cassandra 2.0.x both nodetool and cqlsh use thrift (port 9160) to communicate with the server. So double check that your hodes accept connections on port 9042

Comment: It was just firewall problem. After allowing traffic on 9160 and 9042, the module established a connection.

Comment: Well, I expected something like that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a firewall problem. After allowing traffic on both 9160 and 9042, the connection is finally established.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the TCP ports 9042 and  9160 on my Centos 7 like so

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: enp12s0
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9042/tcp --permanent
success
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9160/tcp --permanent
success
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

**for the router** 
 I  forwarded the portslike so

[image]

and 
[image]

and just to be sure I forwarded the port 7000 too like so

[image]

and then I checked the ports with http://www.canyouseeme.org and here is the result

[image]

and

[image]

and finnaly I got Dbeaver connected :)

[image]

I hope that will help some people in the near future :)